# Select query to get counts

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 tables that I want to query against. If a record exists in both tables then count record and assign to Both, if record exist in Table 1 (T1 Only), then count it and assign to T1 Only, if record exists in Table 2 (T2 Only), then count it and assign to T2 Only column. Have the result set come out as follows.

```
Both    T1 Only T2 Only
2000    3000    4000
```

Comment: What does it mean for a record to "exist"? Does each record have a `id` number of some kind?

Comment: Maybe Right join and Left join can solve your problem.

Comment: Yes, I will be joining the 2 tables on customer_id. We basically call it "Overlap" records that exist in both tables. So, basically want to know how many customer_ids exist in both tables, how many exist in T1 Only and how many exist in T2 Only. Display the counts as indicated above.

Comment: table schema will help. When you say assign it to T1 what do you mean ?

Comment: The original question may be a little misleading. I do not need to assign the record to anything. I just want the counts. The table schema will be each table has Customer_ID which is the primary key with Name/Address data for the additional fields. I just want the query to show the counts for each if they exist in both tables, T1 only but NOT T2, T2 Only but not T1. So, query results above there are 2000 customers that exist in both tables a match by customer_id, 3000 customers just in T1 and 4000 customers just in T2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [FULL JOIN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/develop-app/outer-joins?view=sql-server-ver15). It will return all records from both tables in the query. See example below for your desired result.

```
CREATE TABLE #Table1 (Id INT);
CREATE TABLE #Table2 (Id INT);

INSERT INTO #Table1 VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6);
INSERT INTO #Table2 VALUES (3), (4), (5), (6), (7);

SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN T1.Id IS NOT NULL AND T2.Id IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Both
    , SUM(CASE WHEN T1.Id IS NOT NULL AND T2.Id IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS T1Only
    , SUM(CASE WHEN T1.Id IS NULL AND T2.Id IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS T2Only
FROM #Table1 AS T1 FULL JOIN #Table2 AS T2 ON T2.Id = T1.Id;
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was looking for here. I used the proper case statement but forgot to use the "SUM" keyword with it to total it up. That was the missing link. Thanks!